# Vectorization of a Sum over 3D array Matlab

Tags: matlab

I'd like to know how to vectorize in MATLAB this code so as to avoid the use of loops :

```
for i=1:n1
for j=1:n2
A(i,j) = sum(B(:,i,j).*C(:,i,j));
end
end
```

where A are a matrix of size n1*n2 and B,C are 3D arrays.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to do it directly

```
A = sum(B.*C,1);
```

Or to remove the first dimension:

```
A = squeeze(sum(B.*C,1));
```

Comment: @user41037 if it asswers your question, please consider to accept his answer .